# PHP: How to execute try block even if exception found?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a try block in which some exceptions will be **definitely thrown** but I don't want to stop the execution of the try block if this happens.

This is the code:

```
try {
    $queryStr = "SELECT * FROM `$current_table` WHERE ...";
    $query = $db->prepare($queryStr);
    $query->execute();

    while($row = $query->fetch()) {

    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This try/catch block is inside a for loop, so `$current_table` will be changing continously. Now this current table can take 4 values `april-june-2014`, `july-september-2014`, `october-december-2014` and `jan-march-2015`. These table names are stored in an array.

Now when it will query the first table and if it is found, then it's well and good but if it is not found then I want to check the other tables and see if those exists. If any of the table is not found, it will throw an exception and then it won't check the other tables.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Not sure why people aren't reading your question properly. Please refer to my answer about using the continue statement.

Comment: @Mephoros the problem isn't obvious at first, at first it looks like he wants run the `try` even if exception is thrown...
@Chinmay show the whole code (include the loop)

Comment: I think it's just a case of odd wording. Examining his code, if the table does not exist, then the rest of the try block shouldn't work at all anywho (can't read rows from a non-existing table in a while loop). But perhaps you're right; we should get more information.

Comment: If I understand it, your code should behave like you want, given the try block is inside the loop.

Comment: @Marek Yes, it is working fine. I actually forgot to add 2 columns in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had some structure problems in tables so because of that I was unable to get data from them. But this code is working fine. **The remaining code in try block will be executed even if there is an exception.** So there is no need to add anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Use a continue statement:

```php
for (/* condition */) {
  try {
    // things
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    continue;
  }

  // won't reach here if exception was caught
}
```

See: http://php.net/continue

Example (try this out on [WriteCodeOnline](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)):

```php
$counter = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  try {
    $counter++;
    if ($counter != 3) {
      throw new Exception("Test");
    }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    continue;
  }

  echo "This only prints when an exception is not thrown (when \$counter is 3). See: \$counter = " . $counter;
}

echo "\n";
var_dump($counter);
```

Comment: continue can only be used in loops

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke You shouldn't downvote without properly reading the question: "This try/catch block is inside a for loop"

Comment: Okay, my fault, sorry for that!

Comment: In your example, the continue is not needed, though.

Comment: Aye but it's just an example showing proof-of-concept. The OP may have things that go on after the try/catch block.

Comment: You should add that to the example.

Comment: I think continue may work but before that I need to add `finally` which was added in PHP 5.5 but it looks like I am using PHP 5.4 or earlier. I will be updating PHP and then I'll see if `continue` works but if it doesn't then I will post the whole code.

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke @Mephoros My code was always right. I didn't had to add finally or continue, not even a single word. Actually I had 6 tables and in 2 of the tables I forgot to add 2 extremely important columns. `catch` block was catching the error but I wasn't ouputting it because in that case execution of try block would have aborted. But now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code that must execute irrespective of exception, into a `finally` block. Check this

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 0):

> > I want to check the other tables and see if those exists

You can use 'SHOW TABLES' query to locate what tables are existed. After it match it to april-june-2014, july-september-2014, october-december-2014 and jan-march-2015 and etc.

```
$needTables = array('april-june-2014', 'july-september-2014', 'october-december-2014', 'jan-march-2015')

$existedTables = reportExistedTablesWrapper();//SHOW TABLES

$tables = array_intersect($existedTables, $needTables);

foreach ($tables as $current_table)
{
    $queryStr = "SELECT * FROM `$current_table` WHERE ...";
    $query = $db->prepare($queryStr);
    $query->execute();

    while($row = $query->fetch()) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This solution is better than relying on exceptions to find existing tables.

Answer (score 0):

try This:

```
try {
    $queryStr = "SELECT * FROM `$current_table` WHERE ...";
    $query = $db->prepare($queryStr);
    $query->execute();

    while($row = $query->fetch()) {

    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //echo $e->getMessage();
}
finally {
    echo "Finally.\n";
}
```